# Keeping multiple StreamWriters open or constatly open a new one?

Tags: c#, performance, file, streamwriter

So I have this application that needs to write to 12 different files 10 times a second a few thousand characters strings via different Tasks, figure something like this:

```
public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> Param1 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        string Param2 = "a path";
        bool Param3 = false;

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 100;
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => { Task.Run(() => SampleMethod(Param1, Param2, Param3)); });
        timer.Enabled = false;
    }

    public static void SampleMethod(Dictionary<string, object> collection, string path, bool check)
    {
        if (check)
        {
            //Serialize collection into file at path
        }
    }
```

I was wondering if I should open a new Stream in every task or instantiate one for each file and keep it open. If the latter this streams should be from 12 to 36 and may be open for up to 8 hrs.
As I said performance is a must.

As requested I'm expanding on what I planned to do in both cases:
Case 1 - Pick from a set of StreamWriters:

```
 public static Dictionary<string, StreamWriter> writers = new Dictionary<string, StreamWriter>();

    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> Param1 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        string Param2 = "a path";
        bool Param3 = false;

        StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(Param2);
        string key = "a key";
        writers.Add(key, wr);

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 100;
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => { Task.Run(() => SampleMethod(Param1, Param2, Param3, key)); });
        timer.Enabled = false;
    }

    public static void SampleMethod(Dictionary<string, object> collection, string path, bool check, string key)
    {
        if (check)
        {
            writers[key].WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collection));
        }
    }
```

Case 2 - Generate and use a new one:

```
public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> Param1 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        string Param2 = "a path";
        bool Param3 = false;

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 100;
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => { Task.Run(() => SampleMethod(Param1, Param2, Param3)); });
        timer.Enabled = false;
    }

    public static void SampleMethod(Dictionary<string, object> collection, string path, bool check)
    {
        if (check)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collection));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you edit the question and show how you open each file? Seeing the sharing and permission options might be important for answering the question.

Comment: I would say that it depends on whether you will write or overwrite the data in the file and also whether someone (something) will use the given files during those 8 hours, if you want to prevent it or if it is required.

Comment: @Viliam I would write in a clear file that I create and nothing else beside this application should be able to open the files while they are being written on. It's not a specific requirement, but looking at the architecture of the system nothing has a reason to open them.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Updated. Those are the first ways that came to mind, but I'm open to suggestions if there is a smarter way to do this

Comment: Could your usecase (the actual problem you are trying to solve) be covered by using a logging framework?

Comment: @Fildor Probably yes, but I don't know if there is a framework out there that handles this much data, and I don't know if my company will allow me to use it. If you have any suggestion I would be more than happy to do my own research

Comment: Well, these are the leads I would dig into: a) Using a logging framework like Serilog in conjunction with dotnet logging API and [high performance logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/high-performance-logging). And b) writing to a database instead ( SQLite? ... ) and if you really _need_ textfiles extracting them from db data later on (perhaps by a separate program).